# Rebol VID MVC: how to update multiple views from model if Rebol doesn't support custom event?

Tags: model-view-controller, rebol

Let's say I have a model/controller with 2 simultaneous VID forms. How will I update my 2 views pointing to the same model if Rebol doesn't support custom events ?

Comment: If you gave a code sample here, it would help a lot.  Basically state "here's something I know that works, ok great" and then "*BUT* here's a thing that holds me back from what I want..."

Comment: Well I don't have yet I waited for suggestion before trying but ok will try this we :)

Comment: There are so many ways to implement an MVC that its not possible to answer unless you give us a hint of how you are approaching this.

Comment: Not so many: you have a model, you want to update automatically 2 views each time a model's field is changed, how do you propagate/broadcast that change in rebol ? Of course the model must be a different object than the views: purpose is separation of entities, rebol tends to create a single file and mix everything.

Comment: I use my liquid Dataflow module to implement MVC type constraints on an atomic level.  but that means your data and GUI has to be liquified, which is the case with GLASS.  Using liquid also means you change programming paradigms (from imperative to dataflow) so it can be quite a change of approach.

Answer (score 4):

I went ahead and had fun implementing a property editor MVC.

this example allows you to create models and views dynamically directly from the GUI, so its pretty good at showing the system in action.

when multiple views edit the same data, you'll see them stay in sync.  multiple models may have multiple views each.

This is just an example, showing how easy it is to build MVC patterns in REBOL.  in deed, many constructs in REBOL are already MVC in spirit, even if they're not explicitly marketed as such.

[image]

```
rebol [
    title: "MVC pattern example"
    purpose: {
        shows an example of a raw MVC pattern in REBOL
        the views can create new models and new views, showing interaction
        between separate models, views  and the controler.
    }
]

model!: context [
    data: none

    views: []

    modify: func [label value][
        set in data label value
    ]


    propagate: func [
        /only label 
        /local view
    ][
        foreach view views [
            either only [
                view/refresh/only label
            ][
                view/refresh
            ]
        ]
    ]
]


view!: context [
    controller: none  ; our controller

    model: none ; our model

    label: none ; what label in data does this view manipulate?

    gui:  [
        across
        space 2x10
        style separator box 275x3 edge [size: 1x1 effect: 'ibevel color: (white * .75)]
    ]

    lbl: none   ; gui face
    fld: none   ; gui face

    refresh: func [/only label][
        ; GENERATE the gui if its not been built for this view yet.
        if block? gui [
            gui: copy/deep gui
            ; add a button for each item of data in the model, clicking on them changes
            ; what the field edits.
            foreach item words-of model/data [
                append gui compose/deep bind/copy [
                    btn (to-string item) [
                        print "^/---"
                        label: (to-lit-word item) 
                        probe label
                        refresh
                    ]
                ] self
            ]
            ; we must bind because the block is being used in new objects created dynamically.
            ; if we don't bind the blocks, they stay bound to the class... important detail.
            append gui copy/deep bind/copy [
                return
                separator
                return
                lbl: h1 200 (to-string label)
                return
                fld: field [controller/modify model label face/text]
                btn "randomize" [controller/randomize model label]
                return
                pad 0x10
                separator
                return
                pad 160x0
                btn "new view" [controller/new-view (model)]
                btn "new model" [controller/new-model]
                btn "close" [unview/only gui]
            ] self
            gui: view/new layout gui
        ]

        ; refresh the gui, when its already built (including on first view)
        if any [
            none? label
            label = self/label
        ] [
            probe model/data
            probe self/label
            fld/text: copy get in model/data self/label
            lbl/text: copy to-string self/label
            show fld
            show lbl
        ]
    ]
]


controller!: context [
    models: []

    ; this just describes how the models should be built, 
    ; it could be a hard-coded in new-model()
    model-data: [sid: "0" name: "unknown" occupation: "unknown"]

    new-model: func [/local model view prev-model prev-view][
        unless empty? models [prev-model: last models]

        append models model: make model! [data: context model-data ]
        view: new-view model

        if prev-model [
            ; tweak window position which is a bit screwed up in rebol
            prev-view: last prev-model/views
            view/gui/offset/x: view/gui/offset/x  + system/view/no-resize-border/x 
            view/gui/offset/y: prev-view/gui/offset/y + prev-view/gui/size/y + system/view/no-resize-border/y 8
            show view/gui 
        ]

        model
    ]

    new-view: func [model /local view prev-view][
        probe model/data
        if not empty? model/views [
            probe length? model/views
            prev-view: last model/views
        ]
        append model/views view: make view! compose [
            model: (model) 
            label: (to-lit-word first words-of model/data) 
            controller: (self) ; here self is the controller, since we are composing 
                               ; the value within a controller function
        ]

        view/refresh
        if prev-view [
            ; tweak window position which is a bit screwed up in rebol
            view/gui/offset/x: prev-view/gui/offset/x + prev-view/gui/size/x     + system/view/no-resize-border/x 
            view/gui/offset/y: prev-view/gui/offset/y - system/view/title-size/y - system/view/no-resize-border/y - 2
            show view/gui 
        ]

        view
    ]


    ; general case "set" operation
    modify: func [model label value][
        model/modify label value
        model/propagate/only label
    ]

    ; just an example controler method
    randomize: func [
        model
        label
    ][
        modify model label random copy get in model/data label
    ]
]





ids: make controller! []

ids/new-model

do-events
```